# Is it possible correctly deploy ear to Websphere from Intellij Idea and save old bindings?

Tags: intellij-idea, deployment, websphere

I have foo.ear that can be deployed or updated to WAS 7 without problems. foo.ear have some ext resources and group settings that i need merge when deploy to WAS and through console all works perfctly but take lage amount of time to go through all process. So I prefer automatic deploy from  Intellij IDEA (2018) but when IDEA do deployment it drop all current bindings (ext resources and group settings) and i not found any option to mearge or at last save current bindings of app. So my question is could this be done from IDEA or at last from some script(e.g. maven)?

Comment: What exact actions additionally do you have to perform? Do you use Maven/Gradle in project? There are pre / [post processing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/post-processing-tab.html) tabs which you can use to run e.g. ant script before/after you build the artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the thing is you're looking for is `-bindear` option.

You can manually provide build post/pre processing steps with IDEA

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/pre-processing-tab.html

So you can try to invoke this with the ant task where you exec `ejbDeploy` command from that ant task with that option.

More about the task you can found in the documentation:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_9.1.0/com.ibm.ejbdeploy.doc/topics/regenc.html

Comment: sadly i can't use Ant but thank you for give me clue

Comment: you can find me in any social networks under wtsiamruk nickname, we speaking same language maybe i could try help you better, if i will know the details, actually i'm also struggling with ejbdeploy task, so I'm thinking about implementing some plugin for Intellij to help me struggle less with it ;)